# Is there a way to access the empathy roster via the user-menu?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, empathy

I am new to gnome shell (just upgraded my system from ubuntu 10.10 to 11.10 and manually installed gnome-shell) and I am looking for an efficient way to access the empathy roster.
The user-menu has an entry to toggle IM status, but I didn't find a way to access the roster from that menu. In gnome 2 the empathy roster was available by clicking on the chat-entry in the context menu of "Indicator Applet" ...

Is there a way to access the empathy roster via the user-menu?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [empathy-menu extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/259/empathy-menu/) I got exactly what I was looking for: It makes the empathy-roster accessible through a "Chat" entry in the user-menu.